# Sharepoint 2016 On Prem Single sign on with Web API

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016, spfx, webapi

We have a SharePoint 2016 on premise site which uses both the forms based authentication and windows authentication.

We are planning to add SharePoint framework web parts(SPFx) to the site. For that we are developing custom Web API. I am searching on the internet for a solution how to build a single sign on behavior with SharePoint and Custom .Net core web API.

If any one has an idea it will be a great help.

Thanks